# sitemap.xml normal priority setting drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am using xmlsitemap module. I am adding content(content type) for xml sitemap generation. I set 0.5 (normal priority) for one selected content type. This 0.5 priority will not display on sitemap.xml page. If i am choosing different priority than 0.5, it displayed.

Is it possible to display default prority on sitemap.xml page?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Becouse I'm use the same module with default settings and my sitemap.xml looking this [image: this]
Can you show your sitemap module settings, please?